# True conditions, false evaluates

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, if-statement, conditional-statements, false-positive

I would like to ask you for your advice. I program the movement of the *gameObject* based on the position of the Cursor. By conditions, I limit the **min** and **max** position of the *gameObject* on the **X** and **Z** axis. Everything works well until I exceed the limit x *(3.6f)* And here a problem arises, because in Visual Studio when stepping **I definitely have a condition**, but it is **still evaluated as false**. Don't anyone please appear for? Thanks for any reply!

part of the problem code

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you see is just a rounded human readable value ... the value might be not exactly `3.6` but e.g. `3.61` ...

Comment: As derHugo says floating point inaccuracies are legend